# What's wrong with my smb.conf and why can't Windows access the share?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, file-sharing, samba

I'm trying to use Samba to share files between Windows XP and Ubuntu.

I edited the smb.conf and added the workgroup name and netbios name. This is the part that has problems:

```
[Myshare]
    comment = Myshare
    path = /myshare
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
```

When I do `sudo samba restart` I get the following output:

```
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "read_only"
Ignoring unknown parameter "read_only"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest_ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest_ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
```

From my Windows XP machine, I can see the share, but when I try to access it, it says it's not available and I might not have permission to use it. I already changed the permissions of the directory.

When I installed samba, I did `sudo apt-get install samba4` I think these problems might be because I'm using a newer version of samba and it doesn't recognize the old syntax from the smb.conf file.

When I try to run smbpasswd it says cli_pipe_validate_current_pdu: RPC fault code DCERPC_FAULT_OP_RNG_ERROR received from host 127.0.0.1! machine 127.0.0.1 rejected the password change: Error was : NT code 0x1c010002.

Answer (score 1):

That's really quite interesting. I'm using a lot of the same configuration options for my Samba34.

That being said, hit up `man 5 smb.conf` - this will list all the acceptable clauses you can use. Don't forget, also, to make sure each thing is in the correct section. For example, don't have `server string = UBUNTU` under [Myshare]. By convention, each section should start with a lower case letter. I'd expect Samba to be a little bit more robust, but perhaps it isn't being recognised as a share?

Also, I don't believe `read_only` and `guest_ok` are valid entries. The rest of them are valid, so they're most likely not being recognised as applying to any share; they're sitting loose and are hence being ignored.

Start with a light configuration and slowly work your way up. Comment out lines with `#` and add them back until you find out what's doing it. I don't think `[Myshare]` is the bit with the issues; I think you've used `[global]`-only fields under different shares or something like that. The man page should explain where each can be used.

Answer (score 0):

WinXP will behave like that if it is able to connect to the share but the top level directory itself doesn't allow reading. It would be good to double-check the permissions are right. You can verify that the right user is being seen by the samba server by running `smbstatus` while the XP machine is connected to the share. Then verify that the specified Username can read the share's directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the safest way to do it, but you could try something like this.  Then, once you have it working, lock it down with tighter security:

```
security = share 
guest account = publicuser
passdb backend = tdbsam
```

then

```
[publicuser]
comment = publicuser Home Dir
path = /home/publicuser
public = yes
writable = yes
write list = +publicuser
browseable = yes
hosts allow = 192.168.10.10
```

and, in /etc/smbusers

```
# Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2 ...
# root = 
publicuser = Administrator smbguest pcguest guest
# nobody = guest pcguest smbguest
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread was buried a long time ago but Google brought it up when I have an almost identical looking problem as the OP - my logfiles looked v v similar.

**For me it turned out the the line endings in smb.conf were the problem.**

Somehow (when I say somehow I really mean - Because of sloppy typing) I had lots of lines with a whitespace at the end and they were all getting ignored = didn't show up when I used the testparm command - might have been some quirk in copying them down from github. Cleaned up those whitespaces and the config worked a treat!

Comment: You should provide explicit instructions on how you solve the problem.  As currently written this probably should have just been submitted as a comment.